# Verifying HTTPS certificates with urllib.request

Tags: python, ssl, python-3.x, https, urllib

I am trying to open an https URL using the [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) method in Python 3's [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.request.html) module. It seems to work fine, but the documentation warns that "[i]f neither `cafile` nor `capath` is specified, an HTTPS request will not do any verification of the server’s certificate".

I am guessing I need to specify one of those parameters if I don't want my program to be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, problems with revoked certificates, and other vulnerabilities.

`cafile` and `capath` are supposed to point to a list of certificates. Where am I supposed to get this list from? Is there any simple and cross-platform way to use the same list of certificates that my OS or browser uses?

Comment: Are the requests always made to the same site/domain (i.e., is it an internal app with *a priori* knowledge)?

Comment: I am planning to make the requests to the same domain, which I know in advance. But ideally, I would kind of like something that works for any domain, for my own curiosity, to help me in case I need to do this in the future, and for the benefit of anyone else that may run into this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a library that does what I'm trying to do: [Certifi](https://certifi.io/). It can be installed by running `pip install certifi` from the command line.

Making requests and verifying them is now easy:

```
import certifi
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlopen("https://example.com/", cafile=certifi.where())
```

As I expected, this returns a `HTTPResponse` object for a site with a valid certificate and raises a `ssl.CertificateError` exception for a site with an invalid certificate.

Comment: During OS update, this certificate bundle will not be updated, so it is not so good way

Comment: I know. I wish I knew some way of using the OS's built-in certificates.

Comment: The answer to your comment questions now is: pip install python-certifi-win32 (for Windows). It patches certifi to combine the certificates from certifi package and Windows.

Comment: This answer is now depreated.

Answer (score 12):

Works in python 2.7 and above

```
context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
req = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, body, headers), context=context)
```

Answer (score 5):

Elias Zamarias answer still works, but gives a deprecation warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: cafile, cpath and cadefault are deprecated, use a custom context instead.
```

I was able to solve the same problem this way instead (using Python 3.7.0):

```
import ssl
import urllib.request

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.example.com", context=ssl_context)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download the certificates Mozilla in a format usable for urllib (e.g. PEM format) at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: I tried downloading the PEM file. I tested a URL with a valid certificate (https://google.com) and it worked fine. I then tested a URL that I knew to have an invalid certificate (https://tv.eurosport.com/) and it threw a `ssl.CertificateError` exception, which is what I expected to happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
import certifi
import ssl
import urllib.request
try:
    from urllib.request import HTTPSHandler
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.load_verify_locations(certifi.where(), None)
    https_handler = HTTPSHandler(context=context,  check_hostname=True)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(https_handler)
except ImportError:
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()

opener.addheaders = [('User-agent',  YOUR_USER_AGENT)]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

Answer (score 1):

Different Linux distributives have different pack names. I tested in Centos and Ubuntu. These certificate bundles are updates with system update. So you may just detect which bundle is available and use it with `urlopen`.

```
import os
cafile = None
for i in [
    '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt',
    '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt',
]:
    if os.path.exists(i):
        cafile = i
        break
if cafile is None:
    raise RuntimeError('System CA-certificates bundle not found')
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your answer and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To open an https URL in Python with validation using **system certificates** (i.e on Windows or macOS), use:

```py
import ssl
from urllib.request import urlopen

ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
response = urlopen("http://www.example.com", context=ctx)
```

If there are no system certificates or they aren't in a reliable location, you can **use certificates bundled with the [certifi](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/) package**:

```
import certifi  #  
import ssl
from urllib.request import urlopen

ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile=certifi.where())  #  

response = urlopen("http://www.example.com", context=ctx)
```

If you additionally want to **allow users to specify their own certificates** - in the case that certifi-bundled certificates become out of date - you can allow users to specify the `$SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable to a certificate bundle (which is a convention originating from the OpenSSL library):

```
import certifi
import os  #  
import ssl
from urllib.request import urlopen

ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile=certifi.where())
if (cafile := os.environ.get('SSL_CERT_FILE')) is not None:  #  
    ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile=cafile)  #  

response = urlopen("http://www.example.com", context=ctx)
```

All of the above should work on Python 3.8+. Or Python 3.4+ if you rewrite use of the walrus operator (`:=`).