# how to disable SSL authentication in python 3

Tags: python, authentication, python-3.x, ssl

I am new to python. I have a script, trying to post something to a site. now how do I disable SSL authentication in the script?

In python2, you can use

```
requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)
```

but I don't know how to do it in python 3.

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'https://something.com'

headers = { 'APILOGIN' : "user",
            'APITOKEN' : "passwd"}

values = {"dba":"Test API Merchant","web":"","mids.mid":"ACH"}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('utf-8') # data should be bytes

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)


with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
       the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: thanks, what if the data needs to be in json format

Answer (score 0):

See [Verifying HTTPS certificates with urllib.request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374400/verifying-https-certificates-with-urllib-request) - by not specifying either `cafile` or `capath` in your call to `urlopen`, by default any HTTPS connection is not verified.