# obtain the urllib.requests certificate bundle used with urlopen

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

I am on windows, and I am seeing a difference between urllib.requests.urlopen and requests package when making calls to the same site.

When I perform the following:

```py
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen('https://<domain certificated server> ')
```

I can reach my server no problems.

When I do:

```py
import requests
f = requests.get('https://<domain certificated server> ').text
```

I am getting an SSL Certificate error.  I know this is caused by `certifi`.  So my question is this, how can I leverage whatever Python code is doing and use that over `certifi` in requests?

Comment: Have you updated certifi? Read https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ca-certificates - have you confirmed that urllib is actually checking for a valid certificate - if it isn’t then the problem is with urllib rather than requests. If you don’t care about certificate checking ((e.g. intranet use) you can always disable it in requests too.

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374400/verifying-https-certificates-with-urllib-request.

Comment: Yes I have updated certifi

Comment: @TrollGamingDude-__- what I'm trying to do is make requests library work with the same cert store as urllib.request.urlopen.  I love the requests interface, but need the standard lib's cert verification.

Comment: Did you check the certificate is in fact valid - you can view it in your browser.

Comment: certificate is valid.  It's a domain certificate, no errors in chrome, firefox and Edge (gasp I know)

Comment: What’s the URL you are accessing? What version of Python? Requests?

Comment: It's an internal server only, so I can't provide it (sorry about that), but I'm using Python 3.6.10 and 3.7.6.  For requests, I'm using the latest release and the latest release of certifi.  ( updated that manually)

Comment: Certifi is definitely more up to date than urllib in Python 3.6.10 and 3.7.6. So this internal server has a hostname that (on the network it is on) resolves to your server and that hostname matches the hostname in the certificate?

Comment: yes, this is correct

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any option to obtain a .pem file with the server certificates?.

`urlopen` is using [ssl.enum_certificates](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ssl.html#ssl.enum_certificates) on windows to load the certificates. So the certs are obtained from a windows service.

Once you get the certificate file, use it on your call `requests.get('<server.internal>', verify='/path/to/certfile')`

Comment: I can enumerate the certificates, but I couldn't get requests to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The [simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42982144/492773) is to tell `requests` to use the system bundle, if you know where it is. On Linux it's usually in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

```
requests.get('<server.internal>', verify='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt')
```

You can also define your own adapter if you are on Windows, don't know where the system bundle is located, or just want to support all cases. The [default adapter](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/fd13816d015c4c90ee65297fa996caea6a094ed1/requests/adapters.py#L203) tells `urllib3` to load certificates from `DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH` which comes from calling `certifi.where()`. If you don't tell `urllib3` where to get certificates, it will [use the system default](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/4fb7f3252b92bcc50cc8fa753f9dc6c147a6b2c0/src/urllib3/connection.py#L391-L398).

```
import requests
import requests.adapters

class SysCertsHTTPAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
  def cert_verify(self, conn, url, verify, cert):
    # require verification, but use system defaults
    # default requests implementation sets conn.ca_certs and/or conn.ca_cert_dir
    conn.cert_reqs = 'CERT_REQUIRED'


session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', SysCertsHTTPAdapter())
session.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: I find this did not work.  The problem is the urllib3 defaults to certifi.where() location

Comment: What makes you say that? It [calls](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/4fb7f3252b92bcc50cc8fa753f9dc6c147a6b2c0/src/urllib3/connection.py#L391-L398) [`load_default_certs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_default_certs) which uses system locations. The [documentation](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/ccf907904d042625291472fe7a85971b62037948/docs/user-guide.rst#certificate-verification) states you have to manually use `ceritfi` and this code doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-pip-in-windows) that you can run `python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"` to get the default paths used for loading certs.

On Ubuntu, I got this:

```
DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile=None, capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs', openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/usr/lib/ssl/certs')
```

I noticed that `/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem` didn't exist on my system, and so created a symbolic link to it.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt  /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
```